# Overlaying Transparent Wpf over C++ Direct3D application

Tags: c++, wpf, direct3d

I am able to run a Transparent WPF application over C++ Direct3D application but the frame rate drops from 60FPS to 14FPS. Is there any way to improve the performance ? I don't want to create the UI in C++ and I also want transparent controls.

Comment: is the Direct3D application fullscreen and you able to still do it? If so, maybe you can answer my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611170/embed-button-control-into-existing-direct3d-application#26611597 Sorry, I do not know the answer to yours..